# Find the greatest number between "n" numbers without using array?

Tags: c++, algorithm

How to find the greatest number between **"n"** numbers where we have to get **"n"** from the user. But no where array can be used. I think its not possible as we can't create variables during runtime. But if possible then please help me out.

sample output of program:

Enter "n" ( i.e the number of variables to compare) : 5 // any input

Please enter any 5 numbers : 10 15 7 4 11

Greatest is : 15

Comment: of course it is possible. but you need to clarify your question more.

Comment: What does "the greatest number between 'n' numbers" mean?

Comment: no, just a thought of my mind

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Comment: I think this is an account just for posting spam, in algorithm tag asking such a question is ....

Answer (score 9):

You can just successively take the maximum between two numbers. There is no need to store them all.

Example:

```
Input:   1
Maximum: 1
Input:   5
Maximum: 5
Input:   3
Maximum: 5
```

Comment: thanks its a nice alternative..!!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are talking about taking input from the user, i.e the user will have to enter "n" numbers, and that will be obviously in some sort of loop.

```
declare variable x;

While (condition)
{
variable n = get Input from user 

if (n > x)
x=n
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use stack.Just enter n no's into it and pop the no .if stare it in variable(say MAX) and now pop another no.And compare it from MAX.If it is greater than MAX then assign this no to MAX otherwise POP next no.Untill the stack is empty.

Comment: There is no need for a stack here. A loop is needed over all numbers anyway. You need a loop over all numbers to read them in anyway, so you can use this as the advance step of a simple scanline algorithm. This is the scanline algorithm in it's most simple form.